# Issue with making higher or lower game to work Python 3. Multiple if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with multiple if statements. I understand what is wrong with my code i just can't find a solution. So when i run the program  the 'higher' part works but if i guess 'lower' it doesn't. The interpreter goes from reading if statement to the elif statement. That is not what i want. How do i make it check both if statements first before heading onto the elif statements. I've tried nested if but i can't seem to get it to work. 
Thanks in advance.

```
# Higher or lower card game

import random

x = random.randint(1, 14)

y = random.randint(1, 14)

print('The number is ', x, '.')

while True:

    print('higher or lower?')
    if input() in {'higher', 'h'} and y >= x:
        print('Good guess the number was ', y)
        x = y
        y = random.randint(1, 14)
    elif y < x:
        print('Bad guess , the number was ', y)
        break
    if input() in {'lower', 'l'} and y < x:
        print('Good guess, the number was ', y)
        x = y
        y = random.randint(1, 14)
    elif y >= x:
        print('Bad guess, the number was ', y)
        break
    continue
```

Comment: Do you want to input just once per iteration?

Comment: I'm new to the platform seems i have messed up the indentation. I fixed it

Comment: Coldspeed, I want it to prompt me to input a number after printing the value of x. I want the if statements to work independently if possible. So if i choose to answer 'lower' it should read the second block of code and skip the first one. But the elif statements are causing an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You possibly want something along the lines of:

```
while True:

   print('higher or lower?')
   ans_in = input()

   if ans_in in {'higher', 'h'}:

       if (y >= x):
          print('Good guess the number was ', y)
          x = y
          y = random.randint(1, 14)

       elif (y < x):
          print('Bad guess , the number was ', y)
          break

   elif ans_in in {'lower', 'l'}:

       if (y < x):
          print('Good guess, the number was ', y)
          x = y
          y = random.randint(1, 14)

       elif (y >= x):
          print('Bad guess, the number was ', y)
          break

   continue
```

Note that because of the break statements, a "Bad Guess" will end the game. If you want to continue even after getting a "Bad Guess", you can simply remove the break statements.

Comment: Thats how higher lower works, when you're wrong you lose

Comment: Never played the game, tbh :)

Comment: In Britain we used to have a TV show where this game was the staple game probably, called Bruce's Play your Cards Right

Comment: Ah this is what i was looking for. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess is not working because you get inputs twice in each cycle.

You should try with this:

```
import random

x = random.randint(1, 14)

y = random.randint(1, 14)

print('The number is ', x, '.')

while True:

    print('higher or lower?')
    guess = input()
    if guess in {'higher', 'h'} and y >= x:
        print('Good guess the number was ', y)
        x = y
        y = random.randint(1, 14)
    elif guess in {'higher', 'h'} and y < x:
        print('Bad guess , the number was ', y)
        break
    elif guess in {'lower', 'l'} and y < x:
        print('Good guess, the number was ', y)
        x = y
        y = random.randint(1, 14)
    elif guess in {'lower', 'l'} and y >= x:
        print('Bad guess, the number was ', y)
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid command')
        break
    continue
```

So basically every iteration you just take a command in input, and based on that you build your logic.